# What is the name of a method whose output is only dependent of input and the state of the object?

Tags: c#, java, c++, object

I know the term "pure function" that describes a function whose output is only dependent on the input.

Is there a similar name for a method (function of an object) whose output is dependent only of the input and the state of the object?

Comment: You mean with no dependencies on the environment (I/O)?

Comment: Do you think such a method has enough interesting properties to deserve a name?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of object methods that they affect the state of the object or return something dependant on the state of the object?

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, but also no dependency on global data, random generator etc.

Comment: The object that a method is called on is just an input, so I don't see why the existing term doesn't fit. I guess "pure member function" if you want to be arbitrarily specific.

Comment: I find this a bid odd because in OO languages one of the elements defining the state of an object can be pointers to an other object. So the returned value can be dependent on the other object and so be different for different calls without changing the state of the first object.

Comment: @Dave: that depends how you define "the state of the first object" - to someone who's interested in this kind of classification, an object with a pointer to another object that's mutable wouldn't be described as "immutable" itself. The state of the second object would be considered part of the state of the first object.

Answer (score 1):

[Bertrand Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Meyer), inventor of the [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29) programming language and author of the book [Object-oriented software construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction), calls them "query methods".

Answer (score 0):

I would call it state-dependent method

depending on `State` (design-pattern) instance of object is in, you get different result (not only output) or extension